# Why these unambiguous expressions are different in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript

doing some JavaScript learning and playing around with the syntax. In JavaScript semicolons are optional. It is recommended to use them, but it seems the specification does not impose them in some cases.
In particular it is said that when there is no ambiguity, then it does not make a difference whether you use them or not.

I found this example (an exercise from a blog I googled), but no explanation. I think the semicolon should not make a difference here, but it does. I don't see an ambiguity here, why is it supposed to be different. I tried to play around with some examples, it really seems different. Can't wrap my head around that :-(

```
var y = x + f
(a+b).toString()
```

and

```
var y = x + f;
(a+b).toString();
```

Would be cool if some guru could shed light on this one.

Comment: didn't even know this to be honest. but this sheds a bit of light on the matter http://www.codecademy.com/blog/78-your-guide-to-semicolons-in-javascript

Comment: Every browser uses its own javascript interpreter (more or less). There are some interpreter, which need the semicolon. It tells them, where the end of the statement actually is. I would recommend to actually use the semicolon everytime so you don't face these problems

Comment: Rule of thumb: use semicolons as statement separators, even if they're not necessary as statement _terminators_.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The `f` followed by whitespace and a `(` can be interpreted as a function call. Placing a semicolon will prevent this.

Comment: Damn, you beat me too it :)

Comment: It happens to the best of us. I spent 3 days debugging a missing `var` :D

Answer (score 7):

The ECMAScript Standard Specification mentions the rules of Automatic Semicolon Insertion in [section 11.9.1](http://people.mozilla.org/~jorendorff/es6-draft.html#sec-rules-of-automatic-semicolon-insertion), and the second rule described there is what we need to read:

> When, as the Script or Module is parsed from left to right, the end of the input stream of tokens is encountered and **the parser is unable to parse the input token stream as a single complete ECMAScript Script** or Module, then a semicolon is automatically inserted at the end of the input stream. <sub>emphasis mine</sub>

So there we go. In over-simplified layman language, the semi-colon is inserted if continuation of parsing doesn't give us valid code.

In your case, if we continue parsing the code, we do get valid ECMAScript code as follows: (since JavaScript isn't white-space sensitive)

```
var y = x + f(a+b)...
```

Thus, a semicolon will not be inserted.

Exceptions to this are described in the third rule (like `return` and `yield` keyword usage), but they don't apply in your code.

Comment: Up for quoting the ECMAScript Standard (which I really should look through at some point)

Answer (score 3):

Whitespace in JavaScript (including line breaks) are not syntaxical. So in the above, with a little bit of rearranging the difference should become clear.

Is this:

```
var y = x + f(a+b).toString()
```

The same as this:

```
var y = x + f;
(a+b).toString();
```

Nope. In the first example, f being called as though it is a function with the variable `a+b` being passes as a parameter of that function.

**NOTE**
There is one case I'm aware of where the above isn't exactly true; return statements.

A linebreak character does act in a syntaxical way for return statements, so this:

```
return {
  tomatoes: 'are yummy'
}
```

would return an object with the property `tomatoes`, whereas this:

```
return
{
  tomatoes: 'are yummy'
}
```

would return `undefined`

Comment: what if instead of f we have a value like 5?

Comment: In that case, it would either be a syntax error, or two statements with a missing semicolon between them.

Comment: Exactly. Names in JavaScript must be a letter followed by one or more letters, numbers or underbars, so '5' is not a valid name, so cannot represent a variable object.